# How to always return a java.util.Vector

Tags: serverside-javascript, xpages

If the value in my control only have one value the following code will return a String, if there are more than one value the code will return a java.util.Vector.

getComponent("mycontrol").getValue();

I want this code to return a vector even if there is only one value.

I have seen several code snippets that converts my string to an Array, but I want to get back a vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to force a singular value to be returned as a java.util.vector (or Array for that matter). The only way would be to test to see if it is a vector, then build a vector if not. You could place it into a function and wrap the call into that... for example (this is untested code so you'll need to verify syntax, etc):

```
asVector(getComponent("mycontrol").getValue());

function asVector(obj) {
  if (obj.constructor === java.util.Vector) {
    return obj;
  } else {
    var x:java.util.Vector = new java.util.Vector();
    x.add(obj);
    return x;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, that worked pretty well, but this worked even better. I changed the obj.contructor to typeof

`function asVector(obj) {
 if(typeof obj === "java.util.Vector") {
  return obj;
 } else {
  var x:java.util.Vector = new java.util.Vector();
  x.add(obj);
  return x;
 }
}`

Not sure I like these comments, they do not format nicely